# Visualise keyboard macros (converting them to human readable key names)

Tags: keyboard-macros

I often find useful/nifty kmacros on the web, like `(kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([return 3 16 14 5 return 21 3 46 return 24 98 return] 0 "%d")) arg)`. Being a curious guy I am, I usually want to know *how* they do what they do.

Given the `(kbd)` function, which can convert a string like `"C-x C-c"` to the internally used key codes (that, AFAIK, are used by kmacros), is there a reverse function for this? Can I get a human readable representation of a keyboard macro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you purely want the human-readable key sequence, the `key-description` function is all you need:

```
(key-description [return 3 16 14 5 return 21 3 46 return 24 98 return])
"<return> C-c C-p C-n C-e <return> C-u C-c . <return> C-x b <return>"
```

---

If you want to know the names of the commands which will be executed by that key sequence, you can get those too -- although the commands that a macro will run will, of course, depend on the keymaps that are active in the current buffer, so you can only get the commands which would run for that particular context.

The keyboard macro editor (command `edit-kbd-macro`) will show you the commands.  Invoke it with: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and then select the macro you want.  For a named macro, you would use <kbd>M-x</kbd> at that prompt.

For your example:

```
(fset 'foo [return 3 16 14 5 return 21 3 46 return 24 98 return])
```

Then, in my current `text-mode` buffer:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `foo` <kbd>RET</kbd>

```
;; Keyboard Macro Editor.  Press C-c C-c to finish; press C-x k RET to cancel.
;; Original keys: RET C-c C-p C-n C-e RET C-u C-c . RET C-x b RET

Command: foo
Key: none

Macro:

RET         ;; newline
C-c C-p
C-n         ;; next-line
C-e         ;; move-end-of-line
RET         ;; newline
C-u C-c .
RET         ;; newline
C-x b           ;; switch-to-buffer
RET         ;; newline
```

Note that `edmacro-format-keys` isn't necessarily producing the exact same output as `key-description`.  Here we see `<return>` in the latter, but `RET` in the former.

Comment: Of course the commands will differ :) What I’m interested in are the keystrokes to produce the same effect, which your solution does perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: In fact I mis-read the question.  I've now added a mention of the `key-description` function, which is really what you wanted (although the macro editor's more detailed output may be preferable in many cases).